# can't retrieve content of a webpage with perl's LWP agent

Tags: perl, lwp

I have a program that can retrieve the content of a specific webpage, but there are some pages where I get an error:

```
Can't get http://www.sitename.com
302 Moved Temporarily at geturl.pl line 30.
```

The site displays fine on a browser.

Wonder what I could do to get the content?

My code is very simple, the standard use of LWP and works fine on most pages.

```
  my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent=>'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)',
    keep_alive=>'1'
  );
  ...
  my $response = $browser->get($url);
```

Thanks!

================

update:

1. Yes this is the actual code I'm using. Is there an explicit option to turn on following 
   redirects?
2. Yes wget works

Thanks

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? The default configuration for `LWP::UserAgent` follows 302 redirects automatically.

Comment: Does it work commandline, using wget or curl? A browser (which?) sometimes does more than just send the GET.

Answer (score 0):

The [LWP::UserAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#ua-requests_redirectable) docs indicate that the `request` method on the user agent will follow redirects automatically. It's unclear from this documentation if `get` uses the same logic.

You could use the request method by creating an [HTTP::Request](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) object. This example uses the `request` method:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -MHTTP::Request -MLWP -e '
  $request=HTTP::Request->new(GET => "http://www.google.com");
  $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;
  print Dumper $ua->request($request);'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read slides from [a talk about some of various modules that can do HTTP in Perl](https://speakerdeck.com/mrallen1/giving-lwp-its-well-deserved-golden-watch); maybe you could try one of the others, like [HTTP::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aTiny):

```
perl -MHTTP::Tiny -E '$res=HTTP::Tiny->new->get("http://www.sitename.com/"); say join "\n", map { $res->{$_} } (qw(response status reason content))'
```